# Is it possible to recover the efficiency of ListConvolve when generalizing the convolution?

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, convolution

I've noticed that, while `ListConvolve` is very fast, it becomes *much* slower when you use anything but the standard `Times,Plus` as your functions (cf. [ListConvolve documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListConvolve.html) to see this in action; it looks like `ListConvolve[ker,list,klist,padding,g,h]`).

As an example, I predefine a 500x500 array and call it `array500`. I then define two functions, `LC` and `LC2`, as follows:

```
LC[ar_] := 
  ar ListConvolve[-{{1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}, ar, {2, -2}, 0, 
    Times, Plus];

LC2[ar_] :=
  ar ListConvolve[-{{1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}, ar, {2, -2}, 0, 
    Times, List];
```

(n.b. that the LC[ar] is also == `ar ListConvolve[-{{1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}, ar, {2, -2}, 0];`, the default)

When I run `LC` on `array500`, it's understandably very speedy: `RepeatedTiming@LC@array500` returns a mere .16s. However, `RepeatedTiming@LC2@array500` takes significantly longer at .974s. It's a 61x slowdown! I'm confused as to why it's so different, especially because it never even has to add the elements together. If I change the option from `List` to `Times`, it still takes about the same (long) time.

Is anybody able to clarify why this huge speed difference exists, and whether there's any way to work around it?

EDIT: I realized that I'm doing `n` products for an `n x n` array with `LC` and `9n` with `LC2` due to my multiplication out front by `ar`, but this doesn't seem to matter much (as I expected it wouldn't, but I wanted to check!)—removing this, there's still ~60-70x slowdown by using `Times,List` over `Times,Plus`.

Comment: Unless there has been a recent upgrade there is not much you can do. `ListConvolve` and `ListCorrelate` could be used in some creative ways if the generalised versions were anywhere near as fast as the default but its never been the case unfortunately.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch that's a real shame! I figured something like that was going on, but that I might as well check just in case.

Answer (score 6):

(1) Convolution with Plus and Times can be done via FFT.

(2) The overall speed complexity cannot be less than the size-of-result complexity.

Point (1) might help to explain why the standard `ListConvolve` is fast under most circumstances.

Point (2) on the examples in this post should help to explain why `LC2` is likely to be slow. To make this clear we can check speed and result size on some examples.

```
LC[ar_] := 
 ListConvolve[-{{1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}, ar, {2, -2}, 0]
LC2[ar_] := 
 ListConvolve[-{{1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}, ar, {2, -2}, 0, 
  Times, List]
```

Here is our baseline test.

```
n = 500;
mat = RandomReal[1, {n, n}];
Timing[ByteCount[LC[mat]]]
Timing[ByteCount[LC2[mat]]]

(* Out[50]= {0.011331, 2000152}

Out[51]= {0.532487, 102056104} *)
```

Notice that the second is around 50 times larger (and 50 times slower) than the first. Now we double the example dimension.

```
n = 1000;
mat = RandomReal[1, {n, n}];
Timing[ByteCount[LC[mat]]]
Timing[ByteCount[LC2[mat]]]

(* Out[54]= {0.033061, 8000152}

Out[55]= {2.091857, 408208200} *
```

Notice the sizes and timings go up both by a factor of 4 or so. No surprise there I think. We'll double the dimension again.

```
n = 2000;
mat = RandomReal[1, {n, n}];
Timing[ByteCount[LC[mat]]]
Timing[ByteCount[LC2[mat]]]

(* Out[72]= {0.170051, 32000152}

Out[73]= {8.448733, 1632800392} *)
```

Again timings and sizes went up pretty much uniformly by a factor of 4.

What this means is that point (2) above is the one at play. The speeds are more or less linear in both cases since doubling input dimension means quadrupling output size and that is the same as what happens to the timings. Again, not much of a surprise because the convolution kernel is of fixed small size.

Comment: What are the chances of getting the generalised versions of `ListConvolve` and `ListCorrelate` matching the speed of the default? Can this be added to the development pipeline?

Comment: I'm probably missing something, but if this is the case, why is `Times,Times` roughly the same factor slower when compared to `Times,Plus`?

In any case, the way the input is passed to the second general function definitely doesn't make it easy to even try to avoid this problem if this is the real problem—at least not at my current proficiency level!

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch2 How might that be done?

Comment: Right, there is more to it than the output size. I will surmise some use is made of fast`Dot` code in the default (fast) case, whereas others cases in effect create lists and apply operators to those after the fact.

Comment: "How might that be done?" -- you mean how can it get added to the development pipeline? While I acknowledge it is not as useful as being able to tweet programs I'm sure someone there might accept that it warrants investgation

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch2 No, I mean in terms of coding. I have no idea how to attain such an improvement algorithmically, at least not in any general way. For some special cases where the operations are restricted to `List` and arithmetic, maybe some improvement could be made. Though I doubt it would compete with the speed of MKL code, as is used for the default case.

Comment: In the first instance I'd work on e.g. `ListCorrelate[{x, y, z}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {-1, 1}, {}, f, g]` maybe where `f` and `g` are listable functions and where the kernel and list are always lists. But I, like presumably others around here, are not privy to the underlying code. BTW are you the developer for these two functions?

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch2I am not the developer although I have done some work on special cases, mostly involving integer inputs (and the usual convolution). After looking some more at where the non-default-heads case goes, I will revise my pessimism somewhat and speculate that possibly the bottleneck has to do with unpacking rather than asymptotically faster underlying methods. For a proof of concept you might try to code a handler using `Compile`, wherein the dimensions and nondefault heads are fixed e.g. to do `LC2` above but maybe with default padding.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I'll give that a shot, or at least give a shot at giving it a shot. By the way, do you have any resources where I might read more about packed/unpacked arrays? I see that terminology used very very frequently here, but I don't know anything about it!

Comment: [This documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/LinearAlgebraPerformance.html) might be helpful. Also [this prior MSE thread](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/what-is-a-mathematica-packed-array) has very good information. And here is a [historic but probably still useful account](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/391/).